# Adobe PDF Services: Cryptic (Meaningless?) Error Messages

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, adobe-pdfservices

I am trying to use the Adobe PDF Services to extract text from company report PDFs and am getting the following generic error message for some of them:

```
    raise SdkException("Request could not be completed. Possible cause attached!", sys.exc_info())
adobe.pdfservices.operation.exception.exceptions.SdkException: description =Request could not be completed. Possible cause attached!, requestTrackingId=(<class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'>, ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out'))), <traceback object at 0x10455d540>)
```

It is not a network problem because:

1. I successfully extracted text from 6 other files at the same time
2. I tried multiple times with each erroneous file

The files are not corrupted because I can view them locally just fine.

The python code I am running is generated by Adobe's Service Account and downloaded to local folder: only the input file name is changed.

I am using a trial account and have only used up 20% of my quota, so it's also not a quota error.

The list of erroneous files are:

1. https://www.asahigroup-holdings.com/en/ir/pdf/annual/2019_all.pdf
2. https://www.csx.com/share/wwwcsx15/assets/File/Responsibility/CSX_ESG_Report_Final_7_30.pdf
3. https://online.flippingbook.com/view/459148139/   (download from there)

Would any one (maybe the Adobe staff) able to provide any insights/advice to the generic error message, so that I can attempt to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the files in my Node.js environment and they run fine. I'm happy to share the output with you if you want. It looks like the error is due to a timeout which I suspect is because of the file size which actually isn't all that large.

Try using the sample that allows you to set custom timeouts. The [full sample is here](https://github.com/adobe/pdfservices-python-sdk-samples/blob/main/src/extractpdf/extract_txt_from_pdf_with_custom_timeouts.py) but the relevant code is below.

```
# Initial setup, create credentials instance.
credentials = Credentials.service_account_credentials_builder()\
    .from_file(base_path + "/pdfservices-api-credentials.json") \
    .build()

# Create client config instance with custom time-outs.
client_config = ClientConfig.builder().with_connect_timeout(10000).with_read_timeout(40000).build()

#Create an ExecutionContext using credentials and create a new operation instance.
execution_context = ExecutionContext.create(credentials, client_config)
```

Comment: Thank you joelgeraci for your insights. Indeed, changing the timeout values allow the PDF files to be properly extracted.

But I encounter a "DISQUALIFIED - File is not suitable for conversion" error with the file:
https://www.kao.com/content/dam/sites/kao/www-kao-com/global/en/sustainability/pdf/klp-pr-2020-e-all.pdf

Would you have any idea why the file is "disqualified"?

Comment: We're actually working on providing better error messages. I'm thinking you got the DISQUALIFIED error because the AI couldn't figure out the layout but I'd need to confirm. It's a very complex document. Do you mind if I send this file to the engineering team as a test file? These are the kinds of files that would really help us train the AI.

Comment: Correction: The DISQUALIFIED error is thrown because the document is over 200 pages. Your document was 225. We have an upper limit of 200. I've requested that when this occurs, we provide a better error and reference the page limit.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. It will certainly help with more meaningful error messages. And yes, please send any of the files to your engineering team for testing: these are all publicly available documents. Looking forward to an improved version of Adobe PDF Services. As is, the outputs are more structured that what we could get from 3rd party open source PDF text extractors.